# Bulk Update multiple records in WEB API C#

Tags: c#, asp.net, json, entity-framework, asp.net-web-api

We have ASP.NET Web API application with EF code first approach. We want to provide the ability to the user to update multiple records in a single instance.

We will have a grid, 4 dropdowns for filters above the same grid. Now If we select the value from two dropdowns & then select 4 checkboxes in a grid, then for those four selected record in Grid we want to bulk update those four records with two selected values.

What is the best way to Bulk Edit multiple records in Grid? 
Which verb should I need to use PATCH or PUT for this?